# angular-cookies DefinitelyTyped

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped, angular-cookies

I'm creating an app using `angularjs` and `typescript`. I am using cookies to store same data about user's login and rights etc. I ran into a problem with angular-cookies.d.ts file.

$cookieStore work just fine but according to [AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore) this service has been deprecated, so I tried using $cookies instead.
Using $cookies caused an error while compiling `Property 'put' does not exist` so I checked the definition and there is really no property with such name in ICookiesService interface.

```
declare module "angular-cookies" {
    var _: string;
    export = _;
}

declare module angular.cookies {

    interface ICookiesService {
        [index: string]: any;
    }

    interface ICookieStoreService {
        get(key: string): any;
        put(key: string, value: any): void;
        remove(key: string): void;
    }
}
```

Is there actually an error in this type definition or am I doing something wrong?
Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the DefinitelyTyped definition has not been updated for Angular 1.4 yet. the ICookiesService interface should be something like:

```
interface ICookiesService {
    get(key: string): string;
    getObject(key: string): any;
    getAll(): any;
    put(key: string, value: string, options?: any): void;
    putObject(key: string, value: any, options?: any): void;
    remove(key: string, options?: any): void;
}
```

In the future, you can feel free to submit a pull request on GitHub to update the definition. I've [created one](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/4209) for this now.

### Update:

The above mentioned pull request was merged so this should no longer be a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm new to this TypeScript story. Next time I will already know or even create a definition myself

Comment: @quicky I'm new to it too but I'm liking it and the community. The [pull request](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/4209) has been merged so it should be available.

Comment: yes you're right, it's pretty nice. Like two weeks ago I didn't even know about TypeScript but it's goin quite fast :)